# How to add ternary number in sql server

Tags: sql-server

i am trying to convert int to ternary number in sql server ， for example ，

when 102 + 1 ， i need the result to be 110

is there a system store procedure or function in sql server which can add int using ternary rule ？

for example ，  when

```
declare @pathid as int 
select @pathid = 102

select @pathid = @pathid +1
```

result should be 103 ， but i the result i need is 110 ， anybody know how to do it ？ thanks

i find a store procedure named “ master.dbo.xp_varbintohexstr” ， but it is convert string to hex string ， not what i am looking for 。

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to store a number as a string. Store the number as a numeric field. Perform arithmetic on it as normal. When you wish to display to a human using a ternary representation, convert to text at that point. In the other direction, if humans input the value in a ternary representation, convert to a number before pushing to the numeric field.